# How to create an new observer on the event catalog_product_save_before

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I want auto generation of meta description for my products by create an new observer on the event catalog_product_save_before with this code :

```
public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {
     $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
     $metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('publisher');
    $product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}
```

In which folder/files  I have to write the code?

Comment: In this method, make sure there is no issue for csv products upload.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to create a new module.
Let's call it `Easylife_Meta`.
`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Meta.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Meta>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Meta>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <easylife_meta>
                <class>Easylife_Meta_Model</class>
            </easylife_meta>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <easylife_meta>
                        <class>easylife_meta/observer</class>
                        <method>autoMetaDescription</method>
                    </easylife_meta>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/Model/Observer.php` - the observe class

```
<?php 
class Easylife_Meta_Model_Observer {
    public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('publisher');
        $product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
    } 
}
```

Clear the cache when you are done.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<class>easylife_meta_Model_Observer</class>` instead of `<class>easylife_meta/observer</class>` in `config.xml` ?

Comment: @kashish NO it shouldn't.

Comment: @Marius I'm using Magento 1.9, changed class to the full class name helped me

Comment: @TheKitMurkit It should work both ways. Using the alias allows proper execution in case your observer is overwritten.