# Write timestamp for addressbook change

Tags: magento-1.9, database, event-observer, mysql, backend

1. Login to the website frontend in a customer account.

**Click on "Account information" and edit some information (firstname, lastname, ...).**
Click on the save button.
Now login to the magento backend and click on **customers -> manage customers**.
Now you see the grid with the correct `"updated_at"` timestamp.

2. Login to the website frontend again.
   Click on "Account information"

**And now click on "Addressbook" and edit some information.**
Click on the save button.
Now go to the magento backend and click on **customers -> manage customers**. `Updated_at` is not changed.

**Question:**
How can we set new updated_at timestamp for the address book also?

Address is its own table and has its own `updated_at` field.
If i want to see the timestamp of customer updated when address is updated, i have to an observer for `customer_save_after` update the timestamp of customer there?

Can you tell me how we can setup an observer for `customer_save_after` update for the timestamp?
In which file i have to add the code?

Thank you and best wishes from germany

Answer (score 0):

Take care I have not tested that code but the idea is here.

In your config.xml you have to add observer declaration :
`<customer_address_save_after>
    <observers>
        <update_customer_after_address_save>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>updateCustomerAfterAddressSave</method>
        </update_customer_after_address_save>
    </observers>
</customer_address_save_after>`

Then in your Observer.php file add the function:

```
public function updateCustomerAfterAddressSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Address $_address */
$_address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
if (!$_address->hasDataChanges()) {
    return $this;
}

/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $_customer */
$_customer = $_address->getCustomer();
$_customer->setUpdatedAt(Varien_Date::now())
    ->save();}
```

---

Magento have "dynamic" observers launched before/after save/load entities in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` in these functions:
 - _beforeSave()
 - _afterSave()
 - _beforeLoad()
 - _afterLoad()

Magento use `$_eventPrefix` variable to make it dynamic. The Customer_Address one is in `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract`. With that you can find the observer hook `customer_address_save_after`.

---

Here is an example that explain how to create an extension with an observer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41280/33619
Note that in your case you have to change the observer node from `<adminhtml>` to `<frontend>` in the `config.xml`

Comment: I check the code and give you a feedback in the next 24 hours

Comment: Can you tell me in which folder i have to create the config.xml file and the Observer.php file?

Comment: You have to create a custom module, the `config.xml` is in `etc/`directory and the `Observer.php` have to be in the `Model/` directory. The creation processus is OK for you or you need an example ?

Comment: The model/ folder is a subfolder. Where i can find it?
The creation processus is not clear for me. I would be very thankfull if you describe the processus

Comment: Of course no problem : there is a response from Marius that explain how to create a module with Observer. Note that you have to change the node in the `config.xml` file from `adminhtml` to `frontend`. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41280/33619

Comment: Do you have whatsapp? i will pay you to do this work. Is this okay for you?
But first i will check your link now. thank you!

Comment: No need to pay me it is a free community I am here to help ! Tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Filename Observer.php**
in folder **/app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/Model**

```
public function autoMetaDescription(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Address $_address */
$_address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
if (!$_address->hasDataChanges()) {
    return $this;
}

/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $_customer */
$_customer = $_address->getCustomer();
$_customer->setUpdatedAt(Varien_Date::now())
    ->save();}
```

**Filename config.xml**
in folder **/app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <easylife_meta>
                <class>Easylife_Meta_Model</class>
            </easylife_meta>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_address_save_after><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <easylife_meta>
                        <class>easylife_meta/observer</class>
                        <method>autoMetaDescription</method>
                    </easylife_meta>
                </observers>
            </customer_address_save_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Filename Easylife_Meta.xml**
in folder **/app/etc/modules**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Meta>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Easylife_Meta>
    </modules>
</config>
```

But now i get this error if i edit a adress and click on save in the frontend:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/Model/Observer.php, line 11

Trace:
#0 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(107): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://www.dev....', 302)
#2 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(750): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://www.dev....')
#3 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirectError('http://www.dev....')
#4 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AddressController->formPostAction()
#5 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('formPost')
#6 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /homepages/16/d280867927/htdocs/dev-brand-top/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Comment: I edit two things : the name of your mehtod in Observer.php must be the same as the `<method>` node in config.xml `autoMetaDescription`. And the `<depend>` node in `Easylife_Meta.xml` is useless because you don't have any depends with Mage_Catalog in your extension, if Mage_Catalog is disabled your extension still work.

Comment: The error you have mean that something is written on the page (response request was sent) before your redirection headers were sent. This kind of errors are hard to find, it is maybe a bad file encoding (BOM at the begining) or maybe a space before the <?php tag. You can add a `die` before `$this->_redirectError` function to see if at least there is nothing written on your page before the redirect. If there is none check your file encoding and that there is no space before the `<?php` tag.

Comment: I also change your observer node : you observed `catalog_product_save_before` instead of the customer address one `customer_address_save_after`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I make the changes. If i click now the save button in the frontend, the script show effect: Only the normal massage: "adress is saves".
But the timestamp in the backend is not changed.

**Easylife_Meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Meta>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Easylife_Meta>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
function autoMetaDescription(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
$_address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
if (!$_address->hasDataChanges())
{
return $this;
}
$_customer = $_address->getCustomer();
$_customer->setUpdatedAt(Varien_Date::now())
->save();
}
?>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <easylife_meta>
                <class>Easylife_Meta_Model</class>
            </easylife_meta>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_address_save_after><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <easylife_meta>
                        <class>easylife_meta/observer</class>
                        <method>autoMetaDescription</method>
                    </easylife_meta>
                </observers>
            </customer_address_save_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```