# Magento - Remove tax from all products quote. (Update)

Tags: magento-1.9, code, code-analysis

I saw there are some post like this but I tried that answer and dit not work.

I am learning how to use magento, and What I wan to try is remove all the tax from the cliente when them have add 3 products to the cart.

I am using an observer event. And the function it run is:

Here is the config.xml

```
<events>
  <checkout_cart_add_product_complete> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <checkout_cart_add_product_complete_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>descuentoiva/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>addCheckout</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </checkout_cart_add_product_complete_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
<events>
```

And this is my actual code for the fuction:

```
public function addCheckout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();                
            if (count($cart->getAllItems()) >= 3) {
                $products = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
                foreach($products as $item) {
                    echo $item->getPriceInclTax()."<br>";                           
                    if ($item->getTaxAmount() > 0) { 
                        $item->setTaxPercent(0);
                        $item->setTaxAmount(0);
                        $item->setBaseTaxAmount(0);
                        $item->save();  
                    }
                }
            $cart->save();              
            }               
            #die("patata"); 
        }
```

But when I look the checkout it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to config your event in config.xml. [Learn here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before)

Now, we need to use this event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_product_update_after`.

In your config.xml

```
<global>
  ..
  ..
  <events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
      <observers>
        <my_module_product_add_after>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>modulename/observer</class>
          <method>checkout_cart_product_add_after</method>
        </my_module_product_add_after>
      </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
  </events>
  ..
  ..
</global>
```

Now function `checkout_cart_product_add_after()` in model/observer.php

```
public function checkout_cart_product_add_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();                
        if (count($quote->getAllItems()) >= 3) {
            $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $item
                   ->setTaxAmount(0)
                   ->setBaseTaxAmount(0)
                   ->save();
            }               
        }               
        Mage::log('my log', null, 'my-log.log'); //creates log file if this function is called 
    }
```

This will set tax to 0 for all items that are in cart. You would want to check `sales_flat_quote_item` table.

Because you would also want to check this event on item update on cart, so you have to set another event for this `checkout_cart_product_update_after`.

you can call same function for this event too.

I haven't tested, but this should work.

Comment: I will try but I thinked that prove i done and dit not work.  And config.xml is configured. When I use again my own computer I will update all data with config.xml and the prove. Ty Adarsh

Comment: It did not work Adarsh

Comment: Any error? And did it create a log fine called my-log?

Comment: Yes it create the log

Comment: Check your var/log folder

Comment: This ir the result of log: 
2016-06-10T07:40:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): my log
2016-06-10T07:43:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): my log
2016-06-10T07:43:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): my log
2016-06-10T07:44:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): my log
2016-06-10T07:44:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): my log

Comment: It means function is getting called but the logic is not working. I will check what's wrong later. Mean time you can check what's happening in database of you can.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. I am learning magento xD. But yes it inside on the fuction because I use a "die" for comprove is there is an error and when i show there is not error i take out that "die"

Comment: Observer usually doesn't fire die(). You should add a log to see if it is bening called, like I have.

Answer (score 0):

Please below code to remove the tax from all quote item:

```
public function addCheckout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();                
        if (count($cart->getAllItems()) >= 3) {
            $products = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach($products as $item) {
                echo $item->getPriceInclTax()."<br>";                           
                if ($item->getTaxAmount() > 0) {
                    $item->setTaxClassId(0);
                    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true); // this line was missing
                    $item->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```