# Delivery date and time based on city

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions, zend-framework, delivery-date

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 with SM Market Template, we have delivery services to few cities, I want to have the city as dropdown list during checkout and to assign the delivery date and time based on each city.

For example we assign Pune city delivery within 2 days from the day order is placed and Bangalor city delivery within 24 hours.

I want the customer to be notified about his order delivery schedule and as well as the the delivery date and time to be included in the invoice contents.

Here, I am asking to suggest me with any available extension, code, idea or a tutorial which can be utilized with our platform in order to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `checkout_submit_all_after` **Event**

**get order details in observer using below code**

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

**get all the detail and send mail programmatically**

Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41280/45103) for event and observer

can refer [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/) for custom mail