# magento1.9 : Check if the customer already exist or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, addtocart, register

How to check whether the customer is already registered user or new user.

If they are a new user the product add to cart logic should be different, If they are a registered user the product add to cart logic should be different.

How to differentiate, and where to edit the login in code?

Comment: whats your logic for new user , first order ??

Comment: actually my product is drinking water can. if they are a new user, they have to buy 3 empty water can, 3 filled water can  at the same time in same brand. i completed the process of adding 3empty and filled can. Now , again the same user buy the same product it should add only filled water not empty water can. If they are a registered user, having the possibilities to add only 3 filled water can in which brand they brought before.. for both the user, if they choose another different brand they have to order along with empty can and filled can.

Answer (score 2):

you can check current users order for new user . if current user has order thats mean he is not new user, otherwise he/she is new user

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();  
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->getCollection();
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter(‘customer_email’, $email);
$newUser =false; 
if(empty(orderCollection->getData()) ){
   $newUser =true; 
}
```

Comment: where to add or edit these code.? Kindly tell me

Comment: create an observer and write this code in observer

Comment: I,m totally new to this concept. how to create obersver and where the observer to create? Kindly explain me clearly

Comment: actually my product is drinking water can. if they are a new user, they have to buy 3 empty water can, 3 filled water can at the same time in same brand. i completed the process of adding 3empty and filled can. Now , again the same user buy the same product it should add only filled water not empty water can. If they are a registered user, having the possibilities to add only 3 filled water can in which brand they brought before.. for both the user, if they choose another different brand they have to order along with empty can and filled can.

Comment: you need to observe `checkout_cart_save_before` this event

Comment: you can check this post for event  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before

Comment: `public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {
     $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
     $metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('publisher');
    $product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
} ` shall i use the same code in my observer

Comment: yes you can use same code

Comment: i'm totally confused in these concepts. can u pls provide coding for my logic

Comment: the observer code above is for auto generate meta description. how can i use it for my concept

Answer (score 1):

For orders where the user was a guest the field `customer_is_guest` on the table `sales_flat_order` will be `1`. Whereas for registered user this will have a value of `0`.

For the guest orders it's easy.

```
$order->Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
$isGuest = $order->getCustomerIsGuest();
//or
//$isGuest = $order->getCustomerId() == 0;
```

But to check if the customer registered or it was already logged in is not that easy.
You cannot get the information from the order object. You need to check the quote object associated to the order. But that may not exist.
You can try something like this:

```
$order->Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) { 
    //customer is guest
}
else {
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
         $method = $quote->getCheckoutMethod();
         if ($method == 'register'){
              //customer registered when placing the order
         }
         else {
              //customer was already logged in when placing the order
         }
    }
    else {
        // there is no way of knowing if the customer registered or was already logged in but for sure an account exists.
    }
}
```