# How to automatically add a comment on order when is placed

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, customer, backend

I have the following situation:

I am on the checkout page, and i have 3 Shipping methods.
If i select a specific method form all 3 and i finish the order, i want a comment to be added automatically on the orders view from backend in this area:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to create an [event-observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before) module & observe `sales_order_place_after`.

Your observer method would look like this:

```
public function logShipping($observer){
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($order->getShippingMethod(), false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
}
```