# Category menu linking direct to product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I have a single product and I'd like to link straight to it from the **category button** is this possible?

For example I have a category called **"custom Cut Board"**

I only have one product attached to the **category**. To reduce clicks I would like it when they click the **category title** it goes straight into the product page.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done by using the **URL Rewrite Management** option in **Magento Admin**.

In Magento Admin:

1. Select from menu bar **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management**.
2. Click on the **Add URLRewrite** button.
3. Select the **category** you want to redirect from.
4. Make a note of the **ID Path** (e.g.: *category/10*) and the **Request Path** (e.g.: *flowerpots.html*)
5. Repeat steps **1 & 2**, but this time select **Custom** from the **Create Urlrewrite** dropdown box.
6. Enter the values in each field:

   - **ID Path** (from step 4)
   - **Request Path** (from step 4)
   - **Target Path** - enter path of your product (or the page you want to redirect to).

     - *example 1:* for product url ***www.myswebsite.co.uk/flowers.html*** enter ***flowers.html***.
     - *example 2:* for product url ***www.myswebsite.co.uk/sale/garden/flowers.html*** enter ***sale/garden/flowers.html***.
7. Select **Redirect Permanent (301)** from the **Redirect** dropdown.
8. Save.

Now when the category is clicked on on your website it will re-direct to the product. [For more see here.](https://support.zero1.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/218332507-How-to-Add-a-Product-Category-or-Custom-Redirect)

OR

You can can do this by creating **observer** `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  Unfortunately it still doesn't go directly into the product page it just takes you to the original category page? Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. Redirect works until a re-index and cache clear is done. Once this is done and I go back into the custom URL rewrite it reverts the target patch to category/id/484 or what ever it was before

Comment: If, its not worked then try by creating a module with mentioned observer. Please check your rewrite rule again and make sure your created rule still exists there.

Comment: Hello, how do I create an observer? I've never worked with that before?

Comment: You can get the example from here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41280/21339