# Magento integration with POS machine

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, api, billing, pos

We are planning to integrate **Magento(1.9) with POS machine** at our physical store.
We need to implement the following features

> 1. When an order is placed online the Magento will share the order
>      details and customer details with the POS machine to print the bills.
> 2. The POS machine will share the daily price changes and
>      inventory/stock details with Magento. With this details, the price listing 
>      on the online store will change.

Is it possible to achieve this? please share your views on this. I am looking more insights into the second requirement. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

For case 1, you can use observer to archive the task.  you can use the observer `sales_order_place_after`. This task must be performed on Magento side.

For details on using observer, you can refer to [How to create an new observer on the event catalog_product_save_before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before)

Observer list: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

For case 2, you can use built-in SOAP API or REST API to finish. I recommend you to use SOAP API.

You should build the API calls on POS machine side. For the procedure on building API call, you can refer to [Official Document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html).

For your case, it involve 2 API call. For update inventory, you can call [cataloginventory_stock_item.update](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.update.html). And for price update, you can call [catalog_product_attribute_tier_price.update](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTierPrice/catalog_product_attribute_tier_price.update.html).

Comment: PLease accept my answer if my method works