# Magento 1.9 observer not activating on event

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an observer I want to run when the following event is triggered:`<sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>`

I am basing my configuration on this:
[How to create an new observer on the event catalog_product_save_before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before)

I have setup my config file as follows:

app/etc/modules/DBCustom_Sales.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <DBCustom_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </DBCustom_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/DBCustom/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <DBCustom_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DBCustom_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_shipment>DBCustom_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment</order_shipment>
                    <order>DBCustom_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <dbcustom_sales before="Mage_Adminhtml">DBCustom_Sales_Adminhtml</dbcustom_sales>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>
            <observers>
                <dbcustom_sales>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>dbcustom_sales/observer</class>
                    <method>setShippingCost</method>
                </dbcustom_sales>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>
    </events>
</config>
```

I have the path to the observer as follows:
app/code/local/DBCustom/Sales/Model/Observer.php

```
class DBCustom_Sales_Model_Observer{
    public function setShippingCost($observer){
        $test = '';

    }
}
```

I am using PHPStorm with breakpoints setup on the $test variable so if the observer is active, it should break at $test, but it currently does not break on $test. I have cleared the site cache multiple times, and have confirmed that the event is being triggered, but nothing happens here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full `app/code/local/DBCustom/Sales/etc/config.xml`?

Comment: Updated with full config.xml

Comment: Thanks, it's late here but shouldn't there be something like this in your models' node as well? `<dbcustom_sales>
    <class>DBCustom_Sales_Model</class>
   </dbcustom_sales>`; also, `<events>` is supposed to be a child of `<global>`.

Comment: Awesome, that did it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<dbcustom_sales>
    <class>DBCustom_Sales_Model</class>
</dbcustom_sales>
```

is (was) missing in the `<models>` node.

Also,  is supposed to be a child of .

Full config.xml might look like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <DBCustom_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DBCustom_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <dbcustom_sales>
                <class>DBCustom_Sales_Model</class>
            </dbcustom_sales>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_shipment>DBCustom_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment</order_shipment>
                    <order>DBCustom_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>
                <observers>
                    <dbcustom_sales>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>dbcustom_sales/observer</class>
                        <method>setShippingCost</method>
                    </dbcustom_sales>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>
        </events>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <dbcustom_sales before="Mage_Adminhtml">DBCustom_Sales_Adminhtml</dbcustom_sales>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```