# Magento 1.9 Customer Account Edited By Admin Hook

Tags: magento-1.9

I am currently running magento 1.9 on my site. 
I am using Nerzarbeiter Customer Group Catalog.

I have added an attributes to my customers with the name is_activated and has_trained_in.

What I am wanting to do is when the admin updated the account to be activated and has assigned trained in is send an email containing a coupon code. I know how to make the coupon code I am just unsure how I would hook into the edit to be able to send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two events where you may hook in during the save action of a customer in the adminhtml controller:

`adminhtml_customer_prepare_save` which is called before saving the data

`adminhtml_customer_save_after` which is called after the customer has been saved.

In both events the customer object is passed to the observer as well the request object with all the form data etc.

Comment: Hello @HelgeB thank you for taking time to respond. Would I need to create a new module which has an observer event for these events? Does this get called automatically?

Comment: Yes you will have to create a new module or use one you already have. In this answer you have a good example for how to create an obsever method that: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before You need to create an observer class and make the configuration in the config.xml for one of the events mentioned following that example

Comment: Thank you! I am accepting your answer as it sounds pretty reasonable now that you have explained it makes sense!

Comment: How would I go about grabbing the original customer info as i need to compare the old state to the new one to send emails based on this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way would be, but if you hook in before the customer has been saved (i.e. `adminhtml_customer_prepare_save` event) you could load the original customer data from the database like this: `if ($customer->getId()){ $oldCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());}` (assuming `$customer` is the object passed to the observer)

Comment: Hi, How would i get this code into a transactional email for when the account is activated? I got the old customer data using origData

Comment: That depends what mail you mean: For example the customer object is passed to the email templates for account activation (method `sendNewAccountEmail` in customer model - I guess you want that mail). In this case you may just set the data into the customer object, for example like this `$customer->setCustomCouponCode('YOUR CUSTOM COUPON CODE')`.
 In the template you can use something like this:  `{{if customer.getCustomCouponCode()}}Youe Code: {{customer.getCustomCouponCode()}}{{/if}}`
 That works only for the event `adminhtml_customer_prepare_save`, because the mails are sent shortly after.