# How can i perform event and observer in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need urgent solution. I'm newbie Magento Learner. How can I complete this task.
**Before Product save -> Build Event -> print die in Observer.**

Comment: Die may not work in Observer. Try using Log instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following solution.

> [How to create an new observer on the event catalog_product_save_before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before)

For Reference check following:

> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-1-9-What-is-the-error-in-my-Observer/td-p/404550